# How to add filter for Gmail (business version) attachment file types

Tags: firewall, gmail, attachment

I need to block certain file types from the attachment inside the company, this is part of the company policy. Can this be done with gmail free services? using a firewall some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an [Attachment Filter](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=97738) in the Attachment Manager, which will prevent your Google Apps gmail accounts from sending and receiving files specified in your filter.